# mysql error: could not start the service mysql on local computer error 193: oxc1

Tags: php, mysql

I was going thru the charset change to utf8 on my local MySQL(5.1) databases, had done some changes only via phpmyadmin to the dbs and straight to my.ini - file. When I booted my pc (win xp pro sp 3), MySQL server is not starting up at all and I can't figure out why. I changed the ini-file back as it was, but no. If I'd re-install the whole thing, do they existing dbs remain just fine (I think so) and after the install they're good to go?

Any clues what could be causing it and what you think about the re-install?

All the help mostly appreciated, my first post here, hope this forum is alive! :)

-jazz

Comment: Welcome to SO. The mySQL error logs or Windows' event log will tell you more about the error.

Answer (score 14):

Delete file `c:\Program Files\MySQL Server\bin\mysqld-nt` which is 0 byte, then you can start the service, or, in Windows 8.1, delete `c:\Program Files\MySQL Server\bin\mysqld` which is also 0 byte.

Comment: on windows 10 I had to delete c:\Program Files\MySQL Server\bin\mysqld, not c:\Program Files\MySQL Server\bin\mysqld-nt

Comment: For some reason my `mysqld.exe` got corrupted and was 0 bytes; went back to the zip file I downloaded and replaced it with a fresh copy and all was good again.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the below path :
   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin and then mysql and mysqld which are of 0 byte.
2. windows+r and type services.msc, then enter,
3. start the MySQL service.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably something broken in your config file - you did back up the original before you made the changes?

Try starting the program directly with the --debug option.

e.g. in a DOS box:

```
> "c:\Program Files\MySQL Server\bin\mysqld -- debug"
```

And check the output and logs.

C.

Comment: Thank you both for answering - this is what I got out from the log:

InnoDB: Operating system error number 32 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means that another program is using InnoDB's files.
InnoDB: This might be a backup or antivirus software or another instance of MySQL. Please close it to get rid of this error.

Basically only thing I had changed to the ini-file was the charset.
Checked out process explorer but no instances of mysqld exist. I'm already getting to the point of reinstalling - if I just could be sure that the old data-folder would just work without any extra hassle..